About the chain rule of the exponential entropy
In the paper unifying framework of information measures  the conditional exponential entropy (see equation 29) is defined as:
$\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(X|Y) = E_y\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f^{\alpha}(x|y)\,dx\right)^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}$
while the exponential entropy (see equation 9) is:
$\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(X) = \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f^{\alpha}(x)\,dx\right)^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}$
I would like to prove the chain rule of exponential entropy with order $\alpha$ by showing that the following expression holds for the continuous random variables X, Y, Z:
$\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(X|Y Z) \geq \mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(XY|Z) - \mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(Y|Z) \geq \mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(X|Z) - \mathcal{E}_0(Y|Z) \geq \mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(X|Z) - \log|\mathcal{Y}|$
where $\mathcal{Y}$ is he range of the random variable Y. I am not sure how to proceed and would like to get your opinion. This is my attempt.
I can show that for arbitrary X and Y:
$\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(X|Y) \geq \mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(XY) - \mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(Y)$
In the paper unifying framework of information measures the joint exponential entropy
is defined using the equality (see definition (13) in the paper).
For $0 < \alpha < 1$, since $t^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}$ is convex for $t > 0$:
$\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(X) = \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f^{\alpha}(x)\,dx\right)^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}} \geq \left(E_Y\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f^{\alpha}(x|y)\,dx\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}} \geq E_Y\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f^{\alpha}(x|y)\,dx\right)^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}} = \mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(X|Y)$
Therefore:
$\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(XY) = \mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(X) + \mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(Y|X) \leq \mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(X) + \mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(Y)$
$\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(X|Y) \geq \mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(XY) - \mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(Y)$
Similarly for $\alpha > 1$. Now for a non-empty Z, we extend the inequality to conditional variables:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}_{r}(X|Y,Z=z) \geq \mathcal{E}_{r}(XY|Z=z) - \mathcal{E}_{r}(Y|Z=z) 
\end{equation}
Taking the expectation over $z$ we have:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}_{r}(X|Y,Z) \geq \mathcal{E}_{r}(XY|Z) - \mathcal{E}_{r}(Y|Z) 
\end{equation}
We now use the non-negativity of $\mathcal{E}_{r}$ to write:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}_{r}(X|Y,Z) \geq \mathcal{E}_{r}(XY|Z) - \mathcal{E}_{0}(Y|Z) 
\end{equation}
Finally, noting that $\mathcal{E}_{0}(Y|Z)  \leq \log |\mathcal{Y}|$ we get:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}_{r}(X|Y,Z) \geq \mathcal{E}_{r}(XY|Z) - \log |\mathcal{Y}|
\end{equation}
Is this proof correct?
Please do not hesitate to comment.Thank you in advance for your help.
